# How to conver std::vector<std::string> to char*[] for C api

Tags: c++, c, arrays, c-strings

The API expects an array of zero-terminated c-strings (char*). The array itself is to be terminated with a null pointer (nullptr).

Comment: Can you please add the APIs in your question? What do you mean by _The array itself is to be terminated with a null pointer (nullptr)._? Can you elaborate that?

Comment: @Azeem An array of C-style strings is an array of `char*`. Each of these `char*` will point to a null-terminated string except the last entry in the array. The last entry in the array is `nullptr` so that the size of the array does not need to be passed around. (I've seen this interface before, but I forget where.)

Comment: @JaMiT: Got it, thanks! :)

Comment: @Azeem
I'm using the exec function family in posix.

Functions of the exec family that require such arrays as arguments have v or e in their name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using std::transform?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> v = {"asd","qwe"};
    const char** c = new const char*[v.size()];
    std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), c, [](const std::string& s) { return s.c_str(); });
    for (size_t i=0;i<v.size();i++)
    {
        std::cout << c[i] << std::endl;
    }
    delete[] c;
    return 0;
}
```

But do mind that the array(here `c`) should be in the same scope as the vector(here `v`) or the vector should not get destroyed before the use of the array(`c`) is over.

If you want a `char**` instead and not `const char**`, you can use `.data()` instead of `.c_str()`

Comment: You don't have to allocate the array manually. I'd use `std::vector<const char *> s;`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat and then use s.data() to access the underlying data?

Comment: @theWiseBrо Yep.

Comment: @@theWiseBrо @HolyBlackCat Yeah, using new and delete directly is sloppy C++.